# ImageLayoutBinding exists, ImageLayoutBindingImpl does not, DataBinderMapperImpl is looking for the impl file. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-databinding

Whenever I try to build an app I've been working on in Android Studio, I get the same error, the "cannot find symbol class ImageLayoutBindingImpl" error.

So far the things I've tried have been rebuilding, cleaning and rebuilding, deleting the mapper file and rebuilding, and using the Invalidate Caches / Restart option. I have also tried deleting ImageLayoutBinding and DataBinderMapperImpl, again to no avail.

The full error message is as follows:

```
Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types 
from the XML file. image is missing it file:D:\Arianwen\Documents\TouristApp\app\src\main\res\layout\image_layout.xml
loc:30:35 - 30:39
****\ data binding error ****
```

Edit: As requested, my image_layout.xml file, the space before the question mark is not present in the actual document, and it is there to stop the data section vanishing into the Stack Overflow back-end.

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout>
        <data>
            <variable
                name="image"
                type="com.example.iamatourist.Image" />
        </data>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photoView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/image_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo_large" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/fav_button_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/fav_button_off"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_white_50percent" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/options_button_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/options_desc"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:menu="@menu/image_options_menu"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image_menu" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/img_title"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:text="@{image.title}" />

        </GridLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Have you enabled `android.databinding.enableV2=true` from **gradle.properties** file.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I just tried that, and it didn't seem to make any difference following just a rebuild

Answer (score 1):

As Shown in your error

```
 msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file.
 image is missing it file:D:\Arianwen\Documents\TouristApp\app\src\main\res\layout\image_layout.xml
```

You have used `image` as a variable in your `image_layout.xml` file but not defined in `<Data>` tag.

Comment: Oh, a capitalisation error. Yay. Although now it "cannot find the setter for attribute 'tools:srcCompat'"

Comment: I'm going to try setting the photo in the issue at runtime, see if that helps.

Comment: add your image_layout.xml file in your question, so we can check.